How can I map out multiple decals on a reel?
So I want to map out multiple Decals on this reel. How can I map it out aesthetically and mathematically correct ?
Looking for a math god to help me with this calculation.

So far I have hardcoded the rotation and positioning of the decals. But I want a mapping function for each decal to be placed on the wheel.
Reel.TSX

import { useRef, forwardRef, ForwardedRef, useState } from "react";
import { useFrame, useLoader } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { Decal, useGLTF, useTexture } from "@react-three/drei";
import * as THREE from "three";
import { GLTF } from "three-stdlib";
import { WHEEL_SEGMENT } from "./Constants";
import { useControls } from "leva";
import { degToRad } from "three/src/math/MathUtils";

type GLTFResult = GLTF & {
  nodes: {
    Cylinder: THREE.Mesh;
    Cylinder_1: THREE.Mesh;
  };
  materials: {
    ["Material.001"]: THREE.MeshStandardMaterial;
    ["Material.002"]: THREE.MeshStandardMaterial;
  };
};

type ReelProps = JSX.IntrinsicElements["group"] & {
  value?: number;
  reelSegment: number;
  map: number;
};

const Reel = forwardRef(
  (props: ReelProps, ref: ForwardedRef<THREE.Group>): JSX.Element => {

    const { reelSegment } = props;
    const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF("/models/reel.glb") as GLTFResult;
    const reel = useRef<THREE.Group>(null);

    useFrame(() => {
      if (reel.current) reel.current.rotation.x += 0.025;
    });

    const cherryMap = useTexture("/images/cherry.png");
    const bananaMap = useTexture("/images/banana.png");
    const appleMap = useTexture("/images/apple.png");


    return (
      <group {...props} ref={ref} dispose={null}>
        <group
          rotation={[reelSegment * WHEEL_SEGMENT - 0.2, 0, -Math.PI / 2]}
          scale={[1, 0.29, 1]}
        >
          <mesh castShadow receiveShadow geometry={nodes.Cylinder.geometry}>
            <Decal
              debug // Makes "bounding box" of the decal visible
              position={[0, 0, 1]} // Position of the decal
              rotation={[0, 0, Math.PI / 2]} // Rotation of the decal (can be a vector or a degree in radians)
              scale={[1.39, 0.39, 0.1]} // Scale of the decal
            >
              <meshBasicMaterial
                map={cherryMap}
                polygonOffset
                polygonOffsetFactor={-1} // The material should take precedence over the original
              />
            </Decal>

            <Decal
              debug // Makes "bounding box" of the decal visible
              position={[1, 0, 0]} // Position of the decal
              rotation={[0, Math.PI / 2, Math.PI / 2]} // Rotation of the decal (can be a vector or a degree in radians)
              scale={[1.39, 0.39, 0.1]} // Scale of the decal
            >
              <meshBasicMaterial
                map={bananaMap}
                polygonOffset
                polygonOffsetFactor={-1} // The material should take precedence over the original
              />
            </Decal>

            <Decal
              debug // Makes "bounding box" of the decal visible
              position={[0.75, 0, 0.6]} // Position of the decal
              rotation={[0, Math.PI / 4, Math.PI / 2]} // Rotation of the decal (can be a vector or a degree in radians)
              scale={[1.39, 0.39, 0.1]} // Scale of the decal
            >
              <meshBasicMaterial
                map={appleMap}
                polygonOffset
                polygonOffsetFactor={-1} // The material should take precedence over the original
              />
            </Decal>

            <Decal
              debug // Makes "bounding box" of the decal visible
              position={[0.75, 0, 0.6]} // Position of the decal
              rotation={[0, Math.PI / 4, Math.PI / 2]} // Rotation of the decal (can be a vector or a degree in radians)
              scale={[1.39, 0.39, 0.1]} // Scale of the decal
            >
              <meshBasicMaterial
                map={appleMap}
                polygonOffset
                polygonOffsetFactor={-1} // The material should take precedence over the original
              />
            </Decal>

            <Decal
              debug // Makes "bounding box" of the decal visible
              position={[-1, 0, 0]} // Position of the decal
              rotation={[0, Math.PI / 2, Math.PI / 2]} // Rotation of the decal (can be a vector or a degree in radians)
              scale={[1.39, 0.39, 0.1]} // Scale of the decal
            >
              <meshBasicMaterial
                map={cherryMap}
                polygonOffset
                polygonOffsetFactor={-1} // The material should take precedence over the original
              />
            </Decal>
          </mesh>

          <mesh
            castShadow
            receiveShadow
            geometry={nodes.Cylinder_1.geometry}
            material={materials["Material.002"]}
          />
        </group>
      </group>
    );
  }
);

useGLTF.preload("/models/reel.glb");
export default Reel;


